# How can I turn logging off / on while database is running? Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade a cluster. The problem is that the versions are far far away, both for the cluster and the extensions.. I managed to dump and restore, modify tables, modify the code, etc..

But now I somehow have to do replication too since we can't afford downtime. Existing replication systems cannot be used due to the massive difference between pretty much everything. My idea is to have all the queries  logged, then an application wrote by me will take these, modify them to comply with the new constraints, and execute them on the new databases (assuming the queries are somewhat compatible in terms of side-effects)

I finished writing the application, but I need now to turn on logging on the old databases so I can replicate after I dump/reload (the database will be in backup mode so I can operate on the committed data; the rest of the data will be in the logs)

After setting all the required configs, it boils down to `logging_collector` which requires restart (unlike others where `pg_reload_conf()` is enough)

Is there some way to turn on logging without restarting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'all';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

to start logging all statements. To turn it off again, run

```
ALTER SYSTEM RESET log_statement;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

But I doubt that that will work as you intend.  First, a statements like `COPY ... TO` will be logged, but the data won't, so you cannot capture that.  There are some other cases, like the fastpath API, that won't be logged (this also affects large objects). Take a look at [pgreplay](https://github.com/laurenz/pgreplay/) which does something like what you intend and look at its limitations.

I recommend that you use a trigger-based replication solution like [Slony-I](https://www.slony.info/).

Comment: This is obviously not working, otherwise I wouldn't ask the question in the first place. This is what I did: `ALTER SYSTEM SET log_directory='/var/lib/pgsql/14.5/data/pg_log'; ALTER SYSTEM SET log_filename='queries.log'; ALTER SYSTEM SET logging_collector='on'; ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement='all'; SELECT pg_reload_conf(); SELECT 'aaa';`. I still get everything in the terminal. If I restart postgres, only then it tells me that it is redirecting output, and the file is created

Comment: Changing `logging_collector` to `on` requires a restart. Perhaps some other setting like `log_min_messages` is disabled. It should work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "It should work".. What should work? Logging to file without restarting? Because that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, that works just fine. I just verified it on my system. As I said, you may have some other configuration settings that prevent logging. Perhaps edit your question and show your *complete* log configuration.

Comment: Since you said that you were trying to change `logging_collector` (which won't work), perhaps you are using the Debian/Ubuntu packages where this setting is disabled. My answer will still work there, but you cannot control the location of the log file unless you activate `logging_collector`.